# Unexpected DateTime DateInterval DatePeriod results

Tags: php, date, datetime

Whilst using DateTime DateInterval and DatePeriod to calculate the intervals between two dates, I've hit some unexpected results when using P1W (weeks) and P1M (months).

If we get the months between 30th September and 29th October, it outputs 'Sep' only.  Changing the end date to 30th October outputs 'Sep' and 'Oct'.  My first thought was maybe it needs to be the last day of the month, but of course, October has 31 days...

```
$dateStart  = '2014-09-30 00:00:00';
$dateEnd    = '2014-10-29 23:59:59'; // Sep
// $dateEnd = '2014-10-30 23:59:59'; // Sep, Oct
// $dateEnd = '2014-10-31 23:59:59'; // Sep, Oct
$dateInt    = 'M';

$start      = new DateTime($dateStart);
$end        = new DateTime($dateEnd);
$interval   = new DateInterval('P1'.$dateInt);
$period     = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $day) {
    var_dump($day->format($dateInt));
}
```

The same kind of thing occurs when trying to get the week numbers between two dates.  Setting the end date to Monday 27th October, doesn't include that week (44) in the results.  Changing the end to Tuesday 28th October however, does include week 44.

```
$dateStart  = '2014-09-30 00:00:00';
$dateEnd    = '2014-10-27 23:59:59'; // Monday - 40, 41, 42, 43
// $dateEnd = '2014-10-28 23:59:59'; // Tuesday - 40, 41, 42, 43, 44
// $dateEnd = '2014-10-29 23:59:59'; // Wednesday - 40, 41, 42, 43, 44
$dateInt    = 'W';

$start      = new DateTime($dateStart);
$end        = new DateTime($dateEnd);
$interval   = new DateInterval('P1'.$dateInt);
$period     = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $day) {
    var_dump($day->format($dateInt));
}
```

Does anyone know if this is a known bug?  If so / if not, does anyone know of the best workaround / fix?

Comment: `2014-09-30` + `1month` = `2014-10-30`. And since your `$end` date is older (or equal) than `2014-10-30`, you will get only one period. This is not a bug, this is how it works.

Comment: @Glavić good point.  Can't believe that didn't occur to me.  I've updated my 'workaround' to explain this is why this has tripped me up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so as pointed out in the comments, the issue is down to my start / end date not being greater than the interval I'm checking for (ie a week, or a month).  Silly balls up to make!

So a workaround would be to set the end date to the last day of the week (for week), or the last day of the month (for month).  To make sure the same issue doesn't happen with the start date, we can also make sure the start date is the Monday of this week, or the first day of this month.

Month example and results with fix;

```
$dateStart  = '2014-09-30 00:00:00';
$dateEnd    = '2014-10-29 23:59:59'; // Sep, Oct
// $dateEnd = '2014-10-30 23:59:59'; // Sep, Oct
// $dateEnd = '2014-10-31 23:59:59'; // Sep, Oct
$dateInt    = 'M';

$start      = new DateTime($dateStart);
$end        = new DateTime($dateEnd);

if($dateInt == 'W') {
    $start  = $start->modify('Monday this week');
    $end    = $end->modify('this Sunday');
} else if($dateInt == 'M') {
    $start  = $start->modify('first day of this month');
    $end    = $end->modify('last day of this month');
}

$interval   = new DateInterval('P1'.$dateInt);
$period     = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $day) {
    var_dump($day->format($dateInt));
}
```

Week example and results with fix;

```
$dateStart  = '2014-09-30 00:00:00';
$dateEnd    = '2014-10-27 23:59:59'; // Monday - 40, 41, 42, 43, 44
// $dateEnd = '2014-10-28 23:59:59'; // Tuesday - 40, 41, 42, 43, 44
// $dateEnd = '2014-10-29 23:59:59'; // Wednesday - 40, 41, 42, 43, 44
$dateInt    = 'W';

$start      = new DateTime($dateStart);
$end        = new DateTime($dateEnd);

if($dateInt == 'W') {
    $start  = $start->modify('Monday this week');
    $end    = $end->modify('this Sunday');
} else if($dateInt == 'M') {
    $start  = $start->modify('first day of this month');
    $end    = $end->modify('last day of this month');
}

$interval   = new DateInterval('P1'.$dateInt);
$period     = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $day) {
    var_dump($day->format($dateInt));
}
```

This *seems* to be a workaround for the problem.

It could also be related to this bug - https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52480

Answer (score 3):

The documentation states in the [comments](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateperiod.construct.php#100730):

> endDate datetime is excluded

So 2014-09-30 00:00:00 - 2014-10-30 00:00:00 contains 1 month

But 2014-09-30 00:00:00 - 2014-10-30 00:00:01 contains 2 months

Also, the documentation states that you can even exclude the startDate, by using a flag in the constructor method call.

Comment: The issue isn't really down to the end date being excluded, it's because I was comparing dates which fall below the interval I was checking for - obvious now it's been pointed out, and a silly mistake to make.  I've updated my answer / workaround to explain this.